# Why do I have to log in 3-4 times a day?

Tags: support, login

I have to log in 3 or 4 times a day. Sometimes my session lives for a day, sometimes 1-2 hours. The problem started about 2-3 weeks ago, and previously my session lived for more than a week.

Browser: Google Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)
OS: Software  Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)

Comment: I can't recall the last time I had to log in again.

Comment: Happens to me all the time on Ipad and never on PC.

Comment: Clearly SO doesn't want you people to continue hanging 'round these parts.

Comment: Maybe someone else is logging into your account.  Have you tried changing your password and seeing if that fixes it?

Comment: NathanOliver: I'll try

Comment: You're still on Lion? o_0

Comment: Happening with me on iPhone (iOS 8.3), nearly everyday (*sometimes even twice in a day*). Agree with Op that this problem started only about a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: @Abhitalks Having the same problem on iPhone (8.4.1, Safari), since about few weeks ago. Never happens on Windows PC (Firefox).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First check cookie settings.
In Chrome go to:

- Settings
- Advanced
- Privacy
- Content
- or chrome://settings/content

Under "Cookies" either:

- "Allow local data to be set"

OR

- "Manage exceptions..."
- Add "*.stackoverflow.com"
- Set "Behavior" to "Allow"

If this doesn't fix it try unchecking "Block third-party cookie and site data". If that does fix it, You can go to "All cookies and site data" and see which 3rd party sites add cookies when you go to SO and add exceptions for those. This is what I see when I clear everything and then log in at Stack Overflow:

[image: Screen shot of the list of cookies in Chrome when the only site the browser has been to is Stack Overflow. The list is long enough that the window has a scroll bar and the first half of the list is visible.]
[image: Screen shot of the list of cookies in Chrome when the only site the browser has been to is Stack Overflow. The list is long enough that the window has a scroll bar and the second half of the list is visible.]

(Both images show cookies from other Stack Exchange and Google sites as well as Imgur and what appear to be ad sites.)

I'm going to assume SO doesn't use flash cookies since this was working for you on a Mac a few weeks ago (unless they added that recently?).

Second, as suggested by Mathijs Flietstra, the next step is to look at any add-ons to your browser that have the ability to change your cookies. In particular, you should check:

- Recently added add-ons
- Recently updated add-ons
- Recently changed add-ons (changes to settings, etc.)

Third, if you are at work it could be that there was a recent change in the sites black/white-listed that's affecting your login. For instance, if you use Facebook to login but they started blocking all things Facebook.

Long shot: [a corrupt profile](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oXDKeqCvbg0). To fix it:

> 1. Exit Google Chrome completely.
> 2. Open Finder
> 3. ~/Application Support/Google/Chrome/
> 4. Locate the folder called "Default"...and rename it as "Backup default."
> 5. Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

Comment: thanks for answer, browser settings allow local data to be set, so I'll try to renew "Default" folder today

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, I'd add the question "Have you recently installed any 3rd party programs which might be cleaning your cookies?"