# Has anyone else been logged out multiple times per day recently?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, login, logout

I rarely close Stack Overflow. Often just suddenly I'll be logged out when I go to a different page, or even up/down voting can kick me to the log in page.

Is anyone else getting this problem lately? If so, perhaps we can nail down what's causing it if we look for similarities between people experiencing this.

My circumstances:

- Google Chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)
- Google authentication
- This happens while actively using the browser - restarting for updates doesn't seem to be the cause. I only lock the PC at night, so my session are very long.

Now that I've created a meta post, it isn't happening as often (typically) but in case it helps, I'm going to start logging whenever it happens. I'm seeing a pattern of it happening early arvo every workday.

- 14:34 25/10/2017 AEST
- 12:58 26/10/2017 AEST - I was browsing through a few questions, then got a access denied type message when attempting to add a comment. Refreshing showed that I had been logged out.
- 13:03 27/10/2017 AEST - Browsing questions. After a few, I got one which had all of the "please sign in" banners everywhere.
- 14:30 30/10/2017 AEST - Much the same. Browsing questions then suddenly...
- 12:00 31/10/2017 AEST - Answered a question, then I couldn't upvote a related comment. These two actions were within a minute of each other.
- 16:12 31/10/2017 AEST - Was trying to open the review menu - but it shows the loader, then closed. Did this a few times before refreshing and noticing I had been kicked again.
- 14:06 1/11/2017 AEST - I clicked on a question, expecting to be logged out. In hindsite I should have checked that cookie first...
- 16:19 1/11/2017 AEST - This one took me by surprise.
- 11:11 2/11/2017 AEST - Well this one stuffs up my pattern...
- 13:23 2/11/2017 AEST - Was going through the low quality posts queue
- 14:36 2/11/2017 AEST - 3rd time today :O
- 10:15 3/11/2017 AEST
- 13:35 3/11/2017 AEST - Was posting an answer. Interestingly I got a captcha upon logging in which is interesting - I don't think I've ever seen one on this site before.
- 10:27 8/11/2017 AEST - Weekend and annual leave since the 3rd. This one is interesting because it shows that I need to be active on the site for this to happen, as I didn't get logged off at all during the time I wasn't on the site.
- 14:30 8/11/2017
- 15:34 9/11/2017

I compared the cookies before and after authentication - and noticed that the `acct` cookie was reintroduced after authenticating. The new one is set to expire at `2018-04-30T01:01:35.094Z` - so I find it hard to believe that the previous cookie expired...

This problem still occurs every workday - but as I don't think adding even more timestamps is going to help this problem, I'm going to stop. If anyone can think of anything to try, or a way to breakpoint when a cookie disappears, please let me know.

Comment: This has occurred to me when I have set my browser to open my tabs from the previous session and also set my browser to delete cookies and data on close. Do you have similar settings?

Comment: Beta browser? Might be something just busted there. We don't normally support dev/beta versions. Having said that, login/auth is high stakes, so I'm gonna keep an eye on this question and responses to see if any similarities show up beyond that.

Comment: same happened with me, win10 and the latest version of chrome (64 bit). Suddenly logged out of the entire SE network without pressing the logout button anywhere or deleting cookies. It's something weird going on with it

Comment: @AdamLear Chrome 62.0.3202.62 is the latest **stable** version on my machines. I don't have such issues, even though I'm having my SO tab open all day during work days. It could be an issue with Google auth, as I'm using the Stack Exchange OpenID to log in (using latest Windows 10 and Chrome, both 64-bit)

Comment: Nope, I don't have any issues whatsoever.  I use Firefox (52.4).

Comment: No issues at all, IE6

Comment: No issues on Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) ***or*** Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I use SE credentials.

Comment: As long as it works on IE6, I think we are good.

Comment: When you go to your Google account ("my account") and check the "apps with account access", is stack exchange listed there with "basic account access"? I assume it is of course otherwise you should never be able to login to begin with.

Comment: Yep, confirmed that stack exchange is in the list. It's absence would have me grant that next time I log in I assume.

Comment: Can confirm, I see that same on Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10.

Comment: What are the odds! Found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269074/being-logged-out-once-or-twice-every-day-fo-the-last-several-days?noredirect=1&lq=1) & [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267977/temporarily-lost-login-while-being-active) duplicate. :D

Comment: And this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305306/why-do-i-have-to-log-in-3-4-times-a-day?rq=1

Comment: @o_O I did find those before posting but those questions are from 2014... they may be related, but they're not duplicates. The cause has much more likely been introduced since then.

Comment: Me too - Chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit), macOS High Sierra (also happened with Sierra). I've had this problem for maybe a month.

Comment: Thank you for tracking the timestamps. That's helpful. I finally had a chance to look into this a bit and... turns out, as far as our sessions table is concerned, none of those sessions have been invalidated on our end. I suppose it's possible that your browser just loses the auth cookie entirely... but I don't know off-hand why that'd happen. Are you perhaps behind a proxy?

Comment: There is a corporate proxy... but I'm pretty sure it isn't used for HTTPS requests. HTTP requests do go through a socks proxy though... Next time it happens I'll note the cookies before I log back in.

Comment: @Shadow Cool, thanks. The cookie to keep an eye on is called "acct".

Comment: Any tips as to how to debug its disappearance @AdamLear?

Comment: I was trying to pay bills online earlier on my wWin 10 box using Chrome 62.x official 64 bit, and suddenly all sites thought I had cookies disabled.  I couldn't get into anything...  I killed all chrome processes and re-started it, and everything was fine.  My point being: I think there may be a Chrome bug related to randomly losing the ability to set/maintain cookies.

Comment: That's pretty intense @silencedmessage - I'm only seeing this in stackoverflow though, other applications I am logged in to are not affected. I suspect we must have different problems...

Comment: @Shadow Quite possible that it's different.  It was only with certain sites though...  I was able to log into other sites and stay logged into a few on tabs that I had open, while others completely crapped out.  I figured it's worth throwing out there. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We fixed something today that might have been related; some code got added to our *flair* code - this thing:

[image: Hotdog baby]

(because everyone loves "Hotdog stand", right?)

The problem that got introduced is that the route accidentally (and indirectly) invoked the code-path that identifies who the current user is, and *if appropriate*: rotates their auth cookies (note: it doesn't matter *whose* flair you load - it can be anyone's - it doesn't have to be yours).

Now imagine that you're reading a blog with your (or someone else's) flair on it; your browser makes a request to load the image, and gets a `Set-Cookie` header in the image response, which it then *drops on the floor* because: heck to cookies from other domains, amiright?

So: there's a very good chance that this is what happened. Sorry about that, if so. This has been fixed today.

It is entirely possible that I [ran into this earlier](https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/938405679873822720)...

Comment: Hah. To think that lairy thing was the cause. I'll keep note over the next couple of days. Thanks :)

Comment: I haven't been logged out all day- so I highly suspect this was indeed the bug I was encountering. :)